# How to correctly use spawn-expect-send for 'git push'?

Tags: git, expect

The code below is adapted from [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702513/9243116) to "Use Expect in a Bash script to provide a password to an SSH command", so as to pass arguments to `git push`. I'm not getting any exceptions for passing the wrong uname+pwd, and conversely passing the correct ones does not actually push anything. How can this be corrected?

**git_push.sh**

```
if (( $# == 2 ))
then
    :
else
    echo "expecting 'username pass', got $@"
    exit 1
fi

user="$1"
pass="$2"
expect - <<EOF
 spawn git push
 expect 'User*'
 send "$user\r"
 expect 'Pass*'
 send "$pass\r"
EOF
```

**Terminal:**

```
$ [path]/git_push.sh
spawn git push
Username for 'https://github.com': foo
Password for 'https://foo@github.com':
```

---

Alternatively (no wildcards):

```
 spawn git push
 expect "Username for 'https://github.com': "
 send "$user\r"
 expect "Password for 'https://$user@github.com': "
 send "$pass\r"
```

Comment: Why are you using `expect` rather than uploading a [ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)? If for some reason you can't, my next option would be [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), not expect.

Comment: @frabjous the ssh key is for authentication's sake. `expect` is for automating the execution of an interactive command. I don't think I'm getting mixed up.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting mixed up.
You don't, but in your case, ssh-keys will replace your`expect` script as you do not need to provide username/PAT

Comment: @NicolasFormichella OK, fair point: switch from 'https' to 'ssh' authentication (I did) so I don't have to rely on `expect`. But doesn't the question about the workings of `expect` retain some validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) questions:

```bsh
expect - <<EOF
 spawn git push
 expect 'User*'
 send "$user\r"
 expect 'Pass*'
 send "$pass\r"
EOF
```

1. single quotes have no special meaning in expect, so you are looking for literal single quotes in the User and Pass prompts. Those prompt will not contain single quotes, so the `expect` command hangs until the timeout (default 10 seconds) happens.
2. after you send the password, you don't wait for the push to complete: the expect script runs out of commands to run and exits too early, killing the git process. After any `send`, you should `expect` something. In this case, you're expecting the spawned command to end which is denoted with `expect eof`

```bsh
expect - <<_END_EXPECT
    spawn git push
    expect "User*"
    send "$user\r"
    expect "Pass*"
    send "$pass\r"
    set timeout -1  ; # no timeout
    expect eof
_END_EXPECT
```

Comment: Not quite for me: `: wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
    while executing
"set timeout -1   # no timeout`

Comment: Woops! There should be a semicolon before the hash. Updated.

Comment: Tcl comments are weird: the comment character can only appear where a command can be valid.